# htaccess regular expression

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I would like to create an htaccess rule that will leave regular urls untouched, but will redirect friendly urls to a page I call display.php with variables.

So if a user enters the address www.mydomain.com/test.php, he will go to test.php.

But if a user enters www.mydomain.com/test or www.mydomain.com/test/, he will go to display.php?view=test

if a user enters www.mydomain.com/test/one/ the server will load display.php?view=test/one

Thanks

I have it working on iis URL rewrite, but something goes wrong when I tried converting the code to mod_rewrite. The attached code causes all pages, even index.php to be redirected to display.php, which is wrong.

```
RewriteRule ^/display\.php$    {C:1}/{C:2}
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$    display.php?view=$1&option=$2
RewriteRule ^/display\.php$    {C:1}
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/?$    display.php?view=$1
```

Comment: What is `{C:1}/{C:2}` supposed to be? I don’t know that syntax in Apache rewriting context - is that something you did not correctly port over from IIS rewriting yet?

Comment: You probably want to start with a RewriteCond to check that what was requested does not map directly onto a physically existing file (your test.php case, that you want to let pass through unchanged.)